# Link in Intent put extra

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to put a link in the method intent.putExtra but I can not. I wrote this code but it does not work because it does not display any link

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=idapp\">LINK</a>")));
```

How can i fix?

Comment: You appear to have some issues with mismatched and misused escaped quotes.  Try logging the data you'd be adding as an extra and adjust until it looks sensible.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `Uri` object based on your URL and add that as data.  The receiver of the `Intent` can then extract it properly.

Comment: No, because I would like to write such as "Shared with MYAPP" MYAPP where is the link and clicking on it opens the google play.

Comment: You can (and should) still do that via Uri object.  See this page for details:

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html

Comment: please, can you post an example ?

Comment: See the URL I posted in my last comment.  Look for the section "Linking from an Android app".  There is exact code there for firing an Intent to go to the Play store.